# RestSharp RestClient not working with ASP.NET Core [FromForm]

Tags: asp.net-core, restsharp

Hi I am writing integration test for my asp.net core project and i am trying to use RestSharp RestClient to send Form Data. My Code is working fine as i am getting the desired result if use postman but if i copy restsharp code from postman and try to implement in my test case its not reaching the controller. Following is my code

Postman - [image]

Test Code -

```
 [Test]
    public void ConvertToJson_CSV()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://localhost:44355/GroupContacts/ConvertToJson");
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        //request.AddFile("files", @"C:\Users\RanaBoy\Desktop\ZTT\ZTTTestFiles\sample500.csv");
        request.AddFile("files", System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\RanaBoy\Desktop\ZTT\ZTTTestFiles\sample500.csv"), "sample500.csv");
        request.AddParameter("optInStatus", "1");
        request.AddParameter("SessionId", _SessionId);
        request.AddParameter("AccountId", _AccountId);
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
        request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        //Assert.That(response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(HttpStatusCode.OK));

    }
```

Controller Code -

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("ConvertToJson")]
    [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ConvertToJson([FromForm] ConvertFileToJsonCommand command)
    {
        var result = await _mediator.Send(command);
        return Ok(result.ResultJson);

    }
```

Model Class -

```
 public class ConvertFileToJsonCommand :  IRequest<ConvertFileToJsonResponse>
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
    public List<IFormFile> files { get; set; }
    public int optInStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Postman doesn't generate the correct code for RestSharp. For example, your code sets the content-type header twice.

The following code should produce the correct request:

```
public async Task ConvertToJson_CSV()
{
    var client = new RestClient("https://localhost:44355/GroupContacts/ConvertToJson");
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST)
        .AddFile("files", "sample500.csv", "C:\Users\RanaBoy\Desktop\ZTT\ZTTTestFiles\sample500.csv")
        .AddParameter("optInStatus", "1")
        .AddParameter("SessionId", _sessionId)
    var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
    //Assert.That(response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(HttpStatusCode.OK));
}
```

Notice that the code uses RestSharp 107. If for some reason it won't work, you can check the difference between Postman request and RestSharp request using HttpTracer ([check the docs](https://restsharp.dev/v107/#delegating-handlers)).